# Ubuntu system not booting from USB stick

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, uefi

I have installed two versions of Ubuntu on two hard drives in my Asus laptop, one running with Ubuntu 14.04 and the other with 15.10. Originally, both systems worked, however, today when booting up and selecting 14.04, it returned an "cannot enumerate usb devices" error, and then froze. 15.10 is starting fine however, this is from where I am writing now.

I made two bootable USB sticks (I tried it from both a Windows machine with Rufus and from Ubuntu 15.10 with unetbootin and the built-in startup disk creator), one with Ubuntu 16.04 and the other with the 64-bit version of Windows 10. All "versions" of the usb sticks return the same results:

Booting from the Windows stick freezes a second after the splash screen with the blue logo appears. Also leaving it for quite a long time (an hour), nothing happens.

Booting from the Ubuntu 16.04 stick shows the initial menu with "Try Ubuntu" and "Install Ubuntu", but it gets stuck at a black screen after selecting either.

The Windows stick is formatted in FAT32 with a GPT partition table, and I made sure it has the file needed for booting.

I have obviously tried changing the boot order, enabled and disabled UEFI boot option, along with several other things.

What could be the reason for this? My aim is the install a clean dual-boot system with Windows on one hard drive and Ubuntu 16.04 on the second.

Comment: Does system boot with no USB devices plugged in? Even if mouse or keyboard, it could be a defective device or port. Some UEFI systems require flash drive as gpt and some will not read gpt even for UEFI booting. Not sure which Asus is.

Comment: No, only a mouse is plugged in, and it is also not booting without that mouse (and without USB stick). Only the 14.04 version on the second HDD is booting. I also tried a USB stick with MBR partition table, which also didn't work.

Comment: Did you update UEFI/BIOS? That resets settings back to defaults and many systems have USB settings in BIOS that has ports turned off. Or maybe off if Secure boot with UEFI is on. Check what settings in UEFI/BIOS are.

Comment: If I turn off UEFI boot mode, then it just boots to the already installed grub. I managed to get a working windows version in it by burning the image to DVD and running it from an external DVD drive. I am not sure how to disable secure boot, there is no such option in my boot manager (F2 screen I mean). I am currently trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 from DVD as well

Comment: Many vendors do not call it secure boot. But have a Setting for "Windows" and "Other".  That is secure boot as even with Windows 7 you have to use "Other" as Windows 7 does not support Secure boot.

Comment: Hm. I am still not sure how to boot from usb. I previously had no problem with that, I suspect it has to do with this cannot enumerate usb devices error. I now have a working dual boot system of win 10 and ubuntu 16.04, but both was installed over an external DVD drive (which was also connected via USB)